# Numpy array slicing vs. for-loop results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

Consider a sphere, composed of shells of varying density.
I have two arrays, one for the outer radius of each shell (`rad[]`) and one for the density of each shell (`den[]`).  I want to calculate the mass, out to a given radius, called `mass[]`.

The following for-loop approach achieves the desired result by first finding the mass of the innermost shell (the inner-radius is zero, so it's a sphere), then the mass of each subsequent shell - added to the previous (summed) mass:

```
mass = numpy.zeros(len(rad))                                   # create array
mass[0] = den[0]**(rad[0]**3)                                  # find inner sphere mass
for i in range(1,len(mass)):
    mass[i] = mass[i-1] + den[i]*(rad[i]**3 - rad[i-1]**3)     # Find mass out to shell i
```

Note: I only need the scalings, so I'm not worried about factors of pi.

Can anyone explain why the following slicing result **does not** achieve the same result?

```
mass = numpy.zeros(len(rad))
mass[0]  = den[0]*(rad[0]**3)
mass[1:] = mass[0:-1] + den[1:]*(rad[1:]**3-rad[0:-1]**3)
```

Comment: You already got an aswer to this question. What happened?

Comment: @IonutHulub: My answer was incorrect (or at least incomplete) so I deleted it, at least temporarily, until I can improve it.

Comment: It was correct. I was about to post the same thing when yours appeared. In the first case he modifies an element in `mass` and then uses that element to compute the next. in the second case the old value of the element is used to compute the new one, because the value of mass will be set only after the expression after the equals sign is evaluated. simple as that.

Comment: @IonutHulub: I wanted to explain why the example `test = linspace(1,10,num=10); test[1:] += test[0:-1]` works differently. (I am almost done with my revision to that effect).

Comment: @zhermes: see my revised answer.

Comment: `mass = (den * np.diff(np.r_[0, rad]**3)).cumsum()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that all the elements in the numpy array will be computed simultaneously. The array `mass[0:-1]` in your second line will be evaluated as `den[0]*(rad[0]**3)` followed by nothing but zeros. (The fact that `mass[1]` will no longer be zero *once the line is calculated* is irrelevant- by then it is too late).

You noted that the example:

```
test = numpy.linspace(1,10,num=10)
test[1:] += test[0:-1]
# [  1.   3.   6.  10.  15.  21.  28.  36.  45.  55.]
```

works differently, as though the addition does happen iteratively. The difference in your example is the addition of a value to the right side- that addition makes it a new array in memory (`x + y` is not the same array as `x`), such that `numpy` no longer treats it as adding to itself. See this example

```
test = numpy.linspace(1,10,num=10)
test[1:] += test[0:-1] + 0
# [  1.   3.   5.   7.   9.  11.  13.  15.  17.  19.]
```

If you want to do a vectorized version of your for loop, you can do:

```
mass[1:] += den[1:]*(rad[1:]**3-rad[0:-1]**3)
mass[1:] += mass[0:-1]
```

Comment: That's what I guessed at first, but then I tried:  `test = linspace(1,10,num=10)`, `test[1:] += test[0:-1]` - and that correctly sums all the way to the given index

Comment: @zhermes: try changing your original code to `mass[1:] += mass[0:-1] + den[1:]*(rad[1:]**3-rad[0:-1]**3)`.

Comment: @zhermes: Interesting. I'm looking into it.

Comment: If it does the calculation simultaneouly, then `test[1:] += test[0:-1] = array([  1.,   3.,   6.,  10.,  15.,  21.,  28.,  36.,  45.,  55.])` should be the same as `test[1:] += linspace(2,10,num=9) = array([  1.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  10.,  12.,  14.,  16.,  18.,  20.])`.  It's not.

Comment: @zhermes I know. There's a difference, and it's interesting for sure.

Comment: That's really strange, but the overall result makes sense.  Thanks very much @David!

Comment: Be careful with these in-place things, they are dangerous, and sometimes may appear to work when they don't. This one is probably fine, but just use cumsum or add.accumulate...

Comment: @seberg what do you mean by 'in-place' things?

Comment: @zhermes I mean if you do in place operations on ufuncs `np.add(a, b, out=c)` or that `a += c` and `a` and `c` share memory. In this simple case it works, but numpy may buffer them, so there are some cases where there is no way to predict what happens.